# how do i loop through each readlistviewitem, check the value, and set it to bold?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, telerik

I have a listview that is loaded with a list of objects that contain an attribute called `AssigneeView` which holds the date that the entry was opened. The `listview's` `ItemTemplate` has a label named "lblHeader". What I want to do is loop through the `ListView`.Items and check each element's `AssigneeView` attribute, if it is `null`, I want to set the `lblHeader.Text` to be bold (indicating it is unread).

I want to create a method that takes an attribute from the `Object` in the Items list called `ticketID` and lookup whether or not the `AssigneeView` field is null for that field and return a `bool`. So it would look something like

```
ForEach item in listview.Items
   if(IsUnread(item.datamember.ticketID)) then
       item.lblHeader.MakeBold
   else
      item.lblHeader.MakeNotBold
```

I'm not 100% on how to dig into the telerik control to get what I need to do this. Any suggestions?

UPDATE:
here's where I am at the moment:

```
using (var client = new QUTIService.QSVCClient())
            {
                var data = client.SearchTickets(this.myGuid, txtSearchString.Text, 100, chkSearchClosed.Checked).ToList();
                lsvResultTickets.DataSource = data;
                lsvResultTickets.DataBind();
                if (data.Count == 0)
                {
                    lblStatus.Text = "No tickets found.";
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var item in lsvResultTickets.Items)
                    {
                        var obj = item.DataItem as QT.FullTicket;
                        if (TicketIsUnread(obj.OriginalTicket.TicketID))
                        {
                            //???
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Ok, so I put it into an event handler. RadListViewItemEventArgs e is the reference. I can get to the label with e.Item.FindControl("lblHeader") and set it to bold just fine. But I'm having trouble unboxing the object from the item. Regular asp controls is usually pretty  straight forward: (Type)e.Item or something like that. But e.Item is of type RadListViewItem, and will not cast to the FullTicket object that is inside of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it turns out that I just had to drill down one more level. I didn't need to pull out another method to do the check for me. I handled this is in the item loaded event handler, here's what I ended up with:

```
protected void ResultItem_DataBound(object sender, RadListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {        
        var dItem = e.Item as RadListViewDataItem;
        var dObj = dItem.DataItem as QT.FullTicket;
        //if no read date, mark as unread (bold)
        if (dObj.AssigneeView == null)
        {            
            var headerLabel = e.Item.FindControl("lblHeader") as Label;
            headerLabel.Style.Add("Font-Weight", "Bold");
            headerLabel.Style.Add("Color", "Orange");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you will need to do is check AssigneeView in the RowDataBound event and then set lblHeader accordingly.  RowDataBound is called for each row in you datasource as it is added to the GridView.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
    if (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "AssigneeView") == null) {
      //Set bold
    } else {
      //Set normal
    } 
}
```

Comment: It is a listview, not a gridview. it does not appear to havea  Row attribute